# Can four different sized yet proportional rectangles fit into a square?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, puzzle

Can anyone find a way to prove that four quadrilaterals of different sizes, but equally proportional dimensions can fit exactly into a square.

[image]

So $\frac{a}{b} = \frac{c}{d} = \frac{e}{f} = \frac{g}{e}$

and, of course, b =   a+c   =   d+e   =   a+f+g  etc.

You can set any dimension to "1", if that helps you.

From the image I made it sure seems that it can be done, but I haven't been able to verify it mathematically yet. Can you? What lengths would those sides be?

As a bonus, can you find any other shape so that four of them, all different sizes but proportional can fill a square? Something along the lines of this crude example:

[image]

Comment: If you set $e=1$ and the ratio of the rectangle to be $x:1$, what other side lengths can you find?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution shown here follows the hint given by @CalvinLin, has a different numerical value to the other answer.

Suppose the configuration of the rectangles is as shown:
[image]

As the rectangles are similar to each other, each has a ratio of $1:x$.

We let $AD = 1$ and $DG = x$ for the moment.

Since the rectangles are distinct, we must have $AB = x^2$.

Here comes the fun part. There are two possible values of $GI$, since both $\dfrac {GI}{GC} = x$ or $\dfrac {GC}{GI} = x$ are valid.

Since $GC = 1+x^2$, $GI = \dfrac 1x + x$ or $x + x^3$.

Similarly, there are two values of $BK$ for each value of $GI$.

If $GI = \dfrac 1x + x$, $DI = \dfrac 1x + 2x$, and we could have $BK = 1 + 2x^2$ or $\dfrac 1{x^2} + 2$.

If $GI = x + x^3$, $DI = 2x + x^3$, and we could have $BK = 2x^2 + x^4$ or $2 + x^2$.

Since a square is formed, we have $DI = DK$. This results in four equations, two cubic and two quartic:

\begin{align}
\frac 1x + 2x &= 2 + 3x^2\\
\frac 1x + 2x &= \frac 1{x^2} + 3 + x^2\\
2x + x^3 &= 1 + 3x^2 + x^4\\
2x + x^3 &= 3 + 2x^2
\end{align}

(Un)surprisingly, the pairs of equations with the same degree are related by a substitution $x \mapsto \frac 1x$.

The quartic equation $2x + x^3 = 1 + 3x^2 + x^4$ can be written as:
$$x^4 - x^3 + \left(\frac14x^2 + \frac74 x^2 + x^2\right) - 2x + 1 = 0$$
$$(x-1)^2 + x^2(x-\frac 12)^2 + \frac74x^2 = 0$$
which is a sum of squares that cannot be zero at the same time, so this quartic equation has no solutions.

The [unique real solution](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=2x%20%2B%20x%5E3%20%3D%203%20%2B%202x%5E2) to the cubic equation $2x + x^3 = 3 + 2x^2$ is:

$$\frac 13 \left(2 - 2 \sqrt[3]{\frac2{61 + 3 \sqrt{417}}} + \sqrt[3]{\frac12 (61 + 3 \sqrt{417})}\right) \approx 1.8105357$$

Correspondingly we have, approximately:
\begin{align}
AD &= 1 &\text{or} \quad0.1046454\\
DG &= 1.8105357 &\text{or} \quad0.1894643\\
AB &= 3.2780396 &\text{or} \quad0.3430319\\
GC &= 4.2780396 &\text{or} \quad0.4476773\\
GI &= 7.7455434 &\text{or} \quad0.8105357\\
BK &= 5.2780396 &\text{or} \quad0.5523227\\
KL &= 9.5560791 &\text{or} \quad1
\end{align}

The second column is the side lengths of each rectangle if the side length $KL$ of the square is set to $1$, and we can check that:
$$\frac {DG}{GA} = \frac {AB}{DG} = \frac {GI}{GC} = \frac {KL}{BK} \approx 1.8105357$$

and the diagram above is constructed using this data.

Comment: This solution is essentially unique; see option 6 in this post: https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2022/12/dividing_a_square_into_similar.html

Answer (score 0):

Consider, for the moment, only the three rectangles with side lengths $a,b$ and $c,d$ and the rectangle formed by removing these two from your diagram. I claim that, in this configuration, all of the labels can be replaced with functions of $a$, as follows[image]

Now, I claim that the ratio of the side lengths of the third rectangle is given by
$$f(a)=\frac{1-\frac{1-a}{a}}{1-a}$$

Suppose then, that $f(a)=na$, then we could partition the remainder into 2 rectangles of the appropriate side length. This gives a cubic equation for each $n$, and general solutions are known for this case, but ugly. Setting $n=2$ in wolfram alpha gives

[image]

Comment: Thank you, and well done Zack - So it can be done. But can you calculate what those values would be, given (say, as you did) that one length of the square is "1"?
Presumably a solution would involve a little quadratic algebra, and using the fact that "e" is a shared length.
(I would be happy to share such a solution to a similar but slightly different problem to the one I'm posting here.)

Comment: I amended my answer to give an exact solution to your problem, but perhaps not in the exact configuration you were looking for. Choosing a more intelligent way of breaking up the remaining block might give nicer solutions. Setting f(a)=1 recovers the golden ratio, etc.

Comment: The similarity to the Golden Ratio also struck me before, but at no point does the familiar GR structure devolve to be bounded by a square.